# Why does Chrome reload the page when I turn on my bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, chrome-for-android, external-keyboard

Lenovo Yoga 10 HD+ tablet with Android 4.4.2.
Logitech Tablet Keyboard

If I am in Chrome and I turn on my bluetooth keyboard, the current page will reload. 
This appears to happen no matter which web page I'm on.

This is obviously a waste of time, and I'd like it to stop. Especially because if I"ve already activated the edit control on the web page, the reload de-activates it and I have to tap again before I can begin typing.

Is there any way to disable this stupid behavior? I haven't seen anything in the settings that would seem to be related.

Updated: Per Dain's question, it happens no matter how many tabs are open (1 or many).

Comment: Do you have multiple tabs open when this behavior occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I turn on my bluetooth keyboard

That is probably detected as configuration change, which triggers a restart of the current activity in android (chrome in your case). Only the app developer can change this behavior, so the only thing you could do is to file a bug report.